# Trying to get property of non-object Laravel (get string)

Tags: laravel, frameworks

I am now working with my "Update function".

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $product = Inventory::find($id);
    return view('/update',compact('product')) ;
}
```

This is my view button in my blade

```
<a href="{{ route('edit',$prod->id) }}"  class="btn btn-raised btn-primary btn-sm">
                view
            </a>
```

It works when I redirect it to my edit blade

but when I changed the $id to $prod_num

```
 public function edit($prod_num)
    {
        $product = Inventory::find($prod_num);
        return view('/update',compact('product')) ;
    }
```

my $id is bigInt and primary key(AU) while $prod_num is a string.

how is gonna work if I want to look for the prod_id

Thank you

Comment: route('edit',$prod->id) your are using $prod and passing product from view. Is this a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `find()` method will looks in the primary key of your model. If you want to get a record by another attribute, you can use `where()` and `first()`:

```
$product = Inventory::where('prod_num', $prod_num)->first();
```

Comment: it says Undefined variable

Comment: $product = Inventory::where('prod_num', $id)->first();

it works. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Great! I wrote the answer based on the second version of your function `public function edit($prod_num) {...`